# Ubuntu installation troubleshooting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I just installed a fresh budgie copy on a PC and then it shows this on the screen and never opens https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgH73.jpg

Comment: Normal boot screen shows Vendor's logo & Ubuntu at bottom. What graphics card/chip? If nVidia, and you did not install nVidia driver as part of install, you will need nomodeset to boot until you install nVidia driver from System Settings. Or try recovery mode which already has nomodeset parameter. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: I installed pop os yday and it worked just fine but I didn't like it so tried to install budgie full installation not minimal, gtx 1660 super is the GPU, after 3 installs, I have to turn off/on the PC a dozen times and one of them logs in, could it be hardware related?

Comment: If it boots once, then this may not show anything, but best to review configuration. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I gave up on budgie and installed pop os, it worked like a charm, so I'm guessing it might have been drivers issue, thanks a lot though.